# Can an entity be updated instead of being inserted using spring-data-jpa when entity ID is not known without issuing a query?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We have a Spring Boot/Data-JPA (1.3.3.RELEASE) application using Hibernate implementation where a CSV file is read and inserted into a database table called FIRE_CSV_UPLOAD. For records that are already present we just update them. 
We retrieve record ID by querying for unique key (a combination of three columns) but this approach is inefficient for thousands of record in CSV file.

My question is how to update record without querying the table for unique key? If I do not query for ID then the record will be inserted instead of update.

I know one way which is to retrieve all records and store their unique key and ID pairs in a Map. Any other suggestions are very much appreciated. The codes are as below,

**Note**: They are minimized for brevity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FIRE_CSV_UPLOAD", 
       uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"account_number" , "account_type", "bank_client_id"})})
public class FireCsv {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="account_number")
    private String accountNumber;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="account_type")
    private String accountType;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="bank_client_id")
    private String bankClientIdNumber;

    ...
    other fields/getters/setters
}
```

--

```
public interface FireCsvRepository extends JpaRepository<FireCsv, Long> {

    @Query("select u from FireCsv u where u.accountNumber = :accountNumber and u.accountType = :accountType and u.bankClientIdNumber = :bankClientIdNumber ")
    FireCsv findRecord(@Param("accountNumber") String accountNumber, 
                       @Param("accountType") String accountType, 
                       @Param("bankClientIdNumber") String bankClientIdNumber);
}
```

--

```
@Service
public class FireCsvServiceImpl implements FireCsvService {

    other fields/methods 
    ...
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public FireCsv save(final FireCsv fireCsv) {

        FireCsv existingFireCsv = fireCsvRepository.findRecord(fireCsv.getAccountNumber(), fireCsv.getAccountType(), fireCsv.getBankClientIdNumber());

        // If record exist then mark as update, if not as insert
        if (existingFireCsv != null) {
            fireCsv.setId(existingFireCsv.getId());
            fireCsv.setRecordStatus(CSVUploadRecordStatus.CSV_UPDATE.getStatus());
        }
        else {
            fireCsv.setRecordStatus(CSVUploadRecordStatus.CSV_INSERT.getStatus());
        }

        fireCsv.setRecordStatusDate(new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        return fireCsvRepository.save(fireCsv);
    }
}
```

Comment: May be you can use UPSERT hibernate Native SQL statement.

Comment: @KarthikPrasad thank you. I like that idea but our concern is portability issue such as switching database e.g. Postgresql to MySQL and vice-versa, and ORM provider. Furthermore there are 100 plus fields in the mentioned table.

Comment: I don't think there is much overhead though. Since both MySQL, Postgress and Oracle supports UPSERT, in the case of switching database you would change only your native insert statement rest such as pojos etc would remain same, finally it boils down to how you want to design your system, Maintainability VS Performance. Though in this case if you are going for maintainability your performance might hit badly

Comment: @KarthikPrasad Yes, I fully agree with you. Now, we have to consider all these aspects of maintainability vs portability vs performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read before deciding to make an update or insert, I dont think there is a way around it.

To make that faster you should add an index to your database 
using the three columns "account_number", "account_type", "bank_client_id".

Alternatively you can try to use an composite id using @IdClass as shown in
[tutorial-jpa-composite-primary-key](http://uaihebert.com/tutorial-jpa-composite-primary-key/)
The JPA provider should than automatically create the index for it.

Comment: We appreciate the suggestion. We will create an index for the three columns, and the tutorial is definitely very informative.